# Why can the compiler find one of these operator overloads but not the other?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, reference, operator-overloading

I am trying to serialize a custom class I have made, given a pointer to an instance of the class. This code fails to compile because it can't resolve the `operator<<(out, myObj)`.

```
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &out, MyObj const *&m);
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &in, MyObj *&m);

void MainWindow::serialize(QDataStream &out)
{
  MyObj *myObj = new MyObj();
  operator<<(out, myObj);
}

void MainWindow::deserialize(QDataStream &in)
{
  MyObj *myObj = new myObj();
  operator>>(in, myObj);
}

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, MyObj const *&) { return out; }

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, MyObj *&) { return in; }
```

The compile error is as follows:

```
MainWindow.cpp:79:33: error: call of overloaded 'operator<<(QDataStream&, MyObj*&)' is ambiguous
MainWindow.cpp:79:33: note: candidates are:
../Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qchar.h:395:28: note: QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, QChar) <near match>
../Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qchar.h:395:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'MyObj*' to 'QChar'
...
```

Interestingly, the compiler only fails to find the first operator overload. I am able to fix this by using object references rather than references to object pointers, but I am curious why this will not compile.

Why would the compiler be unable to find the implementation of the first operator?

Comment: Why do you write the operator call in this syntax? It looks strange.

Comment: I couldn't find the answer to your question. May I ask if you have anything special in mind by using & before a pointer? are you planning to reassign it in the overloaded function?

Comment: @leemes: May I ask what is strange about it?

Comment: It just reads strange. I know it's valid syntax. But why not writing `in >> myObj`? Shorter, more readable, more like the docs, more like other people are used to it.

Comment: @leemes: Yes, it looks a little off the books. Thanks.

Comment: Even when using pointers in your serialize function or some other client code, for the streaming operators you should prefer using references to objects, not to pointers. Then dereference your pointers when passing to the stream: `in >> *myObj; out << *myObj;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28479/discussion-between-a2b-and-leemes)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to come back to this until now. The operator is called with this syntax because if I do `out << myOjb` then the code actually compiles, but uses the wrong operator. This was very unexpected for me because I expect `out << myObj` to be equivalent to `operator<<(out, myObj)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to `operator<<`, you are attempting to cast a `MyObj*` to a `MyObj const *&`.

At first glance, this looks valid.  You are *adding* const-ness, after all.  But **C++ does not allow it**.

Consider this possible implementation of your function to see why.

```
QDataStream &operator<<( QDataStream &out, MyObj const *& refptr )
{
   static const MyObj const_thing;
   refptr = &const_thing;
   return out;
}
```

This code would modify the supplied (non-const) pointer `MyObj *myObj` to now point to an  object that **was declared as const**.

**If you want that particular function signature** You can fix this by providing a const-correct pointer to reference.

```
void serialize(QDataStream &out)
{
  MyObj *myObj = new MyObj();
  const MyObj *myConstObj = myObj; // THIS is the pointer that will be referenced
  operator<<(out, myConstObj);
}
```

Otherwise, consider just removing the reference.

```
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &out, MyObj const *m);
```

Comment: Argh, I remember... This makes my answer invalid, doesn't it? Then I'll delete it. (I knew I better had tested it...)

Comment: Wait, no, I guess my answer still is valid to some degree. `MyObj const *&` is ref-to-const-pointer, right?

Comment: My template reason on the other hand is bullshit, I guess. Qt doesn't define it as a template. The docs suggest to write it that way I wrote it in my answer. But leaving out the const would be no error. I deleted it.

Comment: But shouldn't the compiler give a compile error in the first place?

Comment: @A2B the compiler doesn't know that `operator<<(out, myObj)` is supposed to call this specific function.  If there were no other overloads for `operator<<` you would likely see a more helpful error.

Comment: I guess it's listed in the ~100 defined overloads which the compiler prints when it doesn't find one that satisfies the criteria. In the question we see one such overload.

Comment: @leemes: Is there an actual list? I didn't get your answer. Could you kindly explain more.

Comment: Just wanted to add that passing just a pointer to a `MyObj` doesn't work either. The `<<` operator appears to require the second parameter to be a reference.

Comment: Hi, @CoryKlein.  In the code posted to this question, removing the reference works.  If it's not working for you, it probably has something to do with code you're not showing in the question.

Comment: @DrewDormann - Thanks for letting me know. I may have a separate issue to resolve here.